# unable to click on a div with selenium (ng-click) Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hello everyone forgive I think I can not really explain my problem, I will try again, if they can not understand me very well is that sometimes my English written fails a lot sorry

What I want to try is to automate the access to a web that I leave and link here
[RUNT](https://www.runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaVehiculo)

The first part I have solved that is to enter the data to the form and resolve the im not to robot in send

I'm going to post all the code in python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import pandas as pd
import threading
import time
import csv
import os


# options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument(
#    r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\RADEON\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\user Data\default')
#
# options.add_extension(r"C:\Users\RADEON\Documents\Web Driver\Selenium\exs.crx")

# driver = webdriver.Chrome(
#    executable_path="C:\\Users\\RADEON\\Documents\\Web Driver\\chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe",
#    chrome_options=options
# )
#
# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
#
# driver.get("https://www.runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaVehiculo")
# assert "Consulta Ciudadano - RUNT" in driver.title
#
# wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noPlaca")))
#
#
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noPlaca")))


class Runt:

    def __init__(self, placa, nit, time):
        self.placa = placa
        self.nit = nit
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_extension(
            r"C:\Users\RADEON\Documents\Web Driver\cp.crx")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            chrome_options=self.options)

        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, time)
        self.wait_API = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 150)

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def run(self):

        driver = self.driver
        wait = self.wait
        wait_api = self.wait_API
        driver.get("https://www.runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaVehiculo")

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "noPlaca")))
        placa = driver.find_element_by_id('noPlaca')
        placa.clear()
        placa.send_keys(self.placa)

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "noDocumento")))
        owner = driver.find_element_by_name('noDocumento')
        owner.clear()
        owner.send_keys(self.nit)

        # /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[1]

        wait_api.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH, "//*[@id='captcha']/div/div[2]/a[1]")))

        while (driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='captcha']/div/div[2]/a[1]").get_attribute("innerText") != "Solved"):
            print("Search Solution....")
        print("solution found...")

        if(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='captcha']/div/div[2]/a[1]").get_attribute("innerText") == "Solved"):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[8]/button").click()

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.panel.panel-default>div.panel-heading>h4.panel-title a"))).click()

        vigente = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[@id='pnlRevisionTecnicoMecanicaNacional']/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]")

        print(vigente.get_attribute("innerText"))


runt2 = Runt("aqd470", 63364079, 2)
# runt1 = Runt("aqd470", 45884847, 2)
#
# thread1 = threading.Thread(target=runt1.run)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=runt2.run)
#
# thread1.start()
thread2.start()
# r'C:\Users\RADEON\Documents\Web Driver\csv.csv'
```

Ignore the threads was doing some tests.

When running this program on the aforementioned web waiting to solve the I am not a robot and send the form, and the code appears that I want to get the information

but the information does not appear in the html until clicking on the following div

```
<div class="panel-heading" ng-click="togglePanel('pnlRevisionTecnicoMecanicaNacional');
                        consultarDetalle('RevisionTecnicoMecanicaNacional')">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <i class="i_hoja s_25_o1 ib"></i>
                            <a> Certificado de revisión técnico mécanica y de gases (RTM)</a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
```

U can use this example data to enter "AFD329" For Nplaca,"6656954" For Documento

The other fields can be left as default 
I need to click on that element to load the rest of the query would appreciate a lot if you can help me

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div[1]/h4/a").click()

Comment: it could be dynamic html, can you post url of the page?

Comment: which element you want to interact ?

Comment: Hello everyone forgive I think I can not really explain my problem, I will try again, if they can not understand me very well is that sometimes my English written fails a lot sorry

[link](https://runt.com.co/consultaCiudadana/#/consultaVehiculo)

Comment: @ArKaDiA Update the question with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_ and the error stack trace (if any)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your xpath you are locating the `<a>` under `<h4>`.

Element may required some time to get visible, for that try `explicitwait` until element get visible.

Import below packages :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Try with below code :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((CSS_SELECTOR, ".panel-title a")))
element.click()
```

Its bad practice to use absolute xpath, use relative xpath instead. or try CSS Selector over the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

@NarendraR's answer was in the right direction.

As per your question and the *HTML* you have provided, the attribute **`ng-click`** is applied to the `<div>` node which is generally **not clickable**. So instead of attempting to click the ancestor `<div>` node you need to invoke the `click()` on one of it's descendant node i.e. the `<a>` node.

Again as the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Certificado de revisión técnico mécanica y de gases"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.panel.panel-default>div.panel-heading>h4.panel-title a"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='panel-heading']/h4[@class='panel-title']//a[contains(.,'Certificado de revisión técnico mécanica y de gases')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: DebanjanB Thank you for your help but it does not work I understand what you mention to me, I appreciate your help expand the question to give you more information